# what is the best way to convert string to list in python

Tags: python-3.6

what is the best way to convert string to list in python

Comment: What do you want to achieve? split a string in words? split a string in characters?

Comment: Please add an example of what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking,

```py
someString = "Stack Overflow"
someList = list(someString.split(" "))
print(someList) # This shows ['Stack', 'Overflow']
```

A better way to handle spaces,

```py
someString = " Stack        Overflow    "
someList = list(" ".join(someString.split()).split(" "))
print(someList) # This shows ['Stack', 'Overflow'] instead of ['', 'Stack', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'Overflow']
```

Comment: `str.split` already returns a list. No need to convert it.

Comment: instead of split, is there any other way to do this

Comment: @chapelm what's the reason not using split?